# Tapering/Rounding decimal answers JS calculations

Tags: javascript

Using JS to run a simple formula, but like many JS calculations I've made before the decimal answers go on for way longer than I'd like and make it look sloppy.

Is there I way I can force the calculation to stop at a certain decimal place or force a round up from there?

Thanks!

```
    <script>
    var $u = $('input[name=u]');
    var $a = $('input[name=a]');
    var $h = $('input[name=h]');
    $u.on('keyup',function() {
        var u = +$u.val();
        var a = +$a.val();
        $h.val(u*4.605+a*1.308+28.003).toFixed(1);
    });
    $a.on('keyup',function() {
        var u = +$u.val();
        var a = +$a.val();
        $h.val(u*4.605+a*1.308+28.003).toFixed(1);
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you've tried toFixed().  I believe that is the solution, but you're trying to call it on a jQuery object.  You should call it on the number before passing it into val().

Change your code to:

```
$a.on('keyup',function() {
        var u = +$u.val();
        var a = +$a.val();
        $h.val((u*4.605+a*1.308+28.003).toFixed(1));
    });
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that could be done. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// $('#a').val(Math.PI).toFixed(1); // You're inserting the full value, and then executing
                                    // toFixed on a jQuery Object. Not going to work.

$('#a').val( (Math.PI).toFixed(1) ); // How it should be written
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="a"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Math.floor(number)**
Returns the next integer below given number.
`Math.floor(1.66); // 1`
`Math.floor(-1.66); // -2`

**Math.ceil(number)**
Returns the next integer above given number.
`Math.ceil(1.66); // 2`
`Math.ceil(-1.66); // -1`

**Math.round(number)**
Returns the nearest integer. Similar to `Math.floor(number + 0.5);`
`Math.round(1.66); // 2`
`Math.round(-1.66); // -2`

**number|0   (or ~~number)**
Discards the decimal portion of a number.
`1.66|0; // 1`
`-1.66|0; // -1`

**number.toFixed(decimals)**
Converts a number into a string with the specified number of decimals. Will either pad the result with zeroes or mathematically round to a certain number of decimals.
`(1.66).toFixed(1); // "1.7"`
`(-1.66).toFixed(1); // "-1.7"`

**number.toFixed(decimals + 1).slice(0, -1)**
Returns a fixed-decimal string, but chops the specified number of decimals without rounding.
`(1.66).toFixed(2).slice(0, -1); // "1.6"`